# Associations complement

Tags: functions, associations, filtering

So I'd like to complement two associations through shared keys... not the best description, so here's an example:

```
a = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
b = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 5|>
```

The questions is, how `b` differs from `a` with respect to common keys only, so `c` doesn't matter.

And by differs I mean, what minimal example of `x` fulfills:

```
<|a, x|> ===  <|a, b|>
```

---

I could go with:

```
Complement @@ Normal@{b, a} // Association
```

> ```
> <|"b"->5|>
> ```

but stripping associations seems wrong to me. Is there more generic approach?

p.s. in general case one may want to get inf about missing keys too, then:

```
 Complement @@ Normal @ KeyUnion[{b, a}]
```

> ```
> {"b" -> 5, "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"]}
> ```

Comment: Probably wording is not the best so feel free to rename things I've called improperly.

Comment: Let the question stand so as it is, I like 'em and it is anyway a reference. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Complement seems to work without stripping `Association` in both cases.

```
Complement[b, a]
(* <|"b" -> 5|> *)

Complement[Sequence @@ KeyUnion[{b, a}]]
(* <|"b" -> 5, "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"]|> *)
```

What version are you using?

Comment: I don't remember the reason why I've assumed it won't work... Now I feel stupid. :)

Comment: @Kuba Coding fatigue.  It happens.